# Determining possible moves/path in grid based game

Tags: ios, xcode

BACKGROUND:
I'm working on an game that drops 3 circles onto a grid and allows the user to move one circle at a time by tapping the circle and than tapping another space on the grid. Each move drops more circles on the grid.

The way the game works though is that if there is no clear path to the spot chosen (for instance your blocked in by other circles or your not blocked in but the way the board is at the moment theres no path of open spaces to that spot) the game will alert you that you have tried to make an invalid move and will reject the move.

MY PROBLEM:
I can't figure out a way to get the code to check if the move that was played (tapped) was valid or invalid.

I have given each button a tag with a number corresponding to its spot on the grid (see code .m)
 Example:
[image: Game Board a few turns into the game]
At this point of the game a move from space #70 - > #39 would be invalid where a move from #70 -> #71 would be fine.

-Note: Diagonal moves are invalid as well.

How could I get the code to determine this?

Code:(.m)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
int name;
bool oneSelect;
UIImage *imageName;
UIButton *selectedButton;
NSArray *items;
NSMutableArray *occupied;
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"marble_red",@"marble_blue",@"marble_yellow",@"marble_green",@"marble_purple",@"marble_black",@"marble_orange",nil];

    for (int y=0; y < 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(22 + 30 * x, 100 + 30 * y, 30, 30);
            unsigned buttonNumber = name;
            button.tag = buttonNumber;
            [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", buttonNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview: button];
            name= name +1;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        int space = arc4random()%81;
        int pic = arc4random()%7;
        NSString *string = [items objectAtIndex:pic];
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:space];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:string] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"String(%@) / Button(%@)",string,button.description);

    }

}


-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (!oneSelect) {
        if ([button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] != NULL) {
        button.selected = YES;
        imageName = [button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        selectedButton = button;
        oneSelect = YES;
        }else{
            button.selected = NO;
        }
    }else{
        if ([button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] ==  NULL) {
        oneSelect = NO;
        [button setBackgroundImage:imageName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.selected = NO;

        [selectedButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        selectedButton.selected = NO;
            [self nextMove];
        }else{
            selectedButton.selected = NO;
            button.selected = NO;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"button %ld -- frame: %@", (long)button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
}

-(void)nextMove{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        int space = arc4random()%81;
        int pic = arc4random()%7;
        NSString *string = [items objectAtIndex:pic];
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:space];
        if ([button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == NULL) {
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:string] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            i = i - 1;
        }
        NSLog(@"String(%@) / Button(%@)",string,button.description);
    }
}
```

Also if theres anything I should fix in my code that would better the gameplay, let me know.

Comment: You don't do anything with the `occupied` array but I presume you are using this to track occupied cells.  A better approach would be an array the size of the board, where each element is either true/occupied or false/unoccupied.  Determining if a path exists can be handled by a recursive algorithm that attempts to reach the goal by exploring the path.  If you reach the goal return true and stop searching.  If you don't return false and try the next direction until you have exhausted all possibilities

Comment: You might want to look up [depth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [breadth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). In general this problem falls under [graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal).

Comment: Could you explain exactly how I could go about doing this. I am not very experienced. If you don't want to but know an article that explains it well. That would be helpful as well.  I assume that the true/false array would be an array of 0-80 with each object being true or false. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was to implement an [Iterative Deepening Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)

First, I created a class to represent each 'cell' in the board (because I don't like using `viewWithTag`

**BoardCell.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BoardCell : NSObject


@property (weak,nonatomic,readonly) UIButton *button;
@property BOOL occupied;


-(id) initWithButton:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

**BoardCell.m**

```
#import "BoardCell.h"

@implementation BoardCell

-(id) initWithButton:(UIButton *)button {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        _button=button;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Then I implemented my version of your game (I changed the images to use some that I already had, so I also changed the dimensions of the cell layout). I wasn't quite sure of the 'rules' of your game, so I made some up.  It doesn't check for "game over" but that is trivial.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BoardCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *imageNames;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *board;
@property NSInteger lastMove;

#define BOARDWIDTH 9
#define BOARDHEIGHT 9

@end

static int moves[]={-BOARDWIDTH,-1,1,BOARDWIDTH};

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.imageNames = @[@"redhex",@"bluehex",@"purplehex",@"orangehex",@"greenhex"];

    self.board = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int y=0; y < BOARDWIDTH; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARDHEIGHT; x++) {
            UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(40 * x, 100 + 40 * y, 60, 60);
            button.tag = y*BOARDWIDTH+x;
            [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", button.tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview: button];
            [self.board addObject:[[BoardCell alloc] initWithButton:button]];
        }
    }

    self.lastMove=arc4random_uniform(BOARDWIDTH*BOARDHEIGHT);
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:self.lastMove];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greensquare"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self addRandoms:3];


}

-(void) addRandoms:(NSInteger)randomCount {
    for (int i = 0; i < randomCount; i++) {
        int space = arc4random_uniform(BOARDWIDTH*BOARDHEIGHT);
        BoardCell *cell=self.board[space];
        if (!cell.occupied) {
            int pic = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)self.imageNames.count);
            NSString *string = [self.imageNames objectAtIndex:pic];
            [cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:string] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cell.occupied=YES;
        }
        else {
            i--;
        }

    }
}



-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSInteger buttonId=button.tag;
    BoardCell *cell=self.board[buttonId];

    if (!cell.occupied) {

        BoardCell *startCell=self.board[self.lastMove];
        startCell.occupied=NO;

        if ([self validMoveFromSquare:self.lastMove toDestination:buttonId]) {
            [startCell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangesquare"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greensquare"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            self.lastMove=buttonId;
            cell.occupied=YES;
        }
        startCell.occupied=YES;

    }

    [self addRandoms:3];
}


-(BOOL) validMoveFromSquare:(NSInteger)startSquare toDestination:(NSInteger)destination {

    for (int limit=1;limit<50;limit++ ) {
        NSMutableIndexSet *visitList=[NSMutableIndexSet new];
        if ([self DFSFromStart:startSquare toGoal:destination withLimit:limit andVisitList:visitList]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;

}

-(BOOL) DFSFromStart:(NSInteger)start toGoal:(NSInteger)goal withLimit:(NSInteger)limit andVisitList:(NSMutableIndexSet *)visitList {

    if (start==goal) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (limit >=0) {

        if (((BoardCell *)self.board[start]).occupied) {
            return NO;
        }

        [visitList addIndex:start];

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            NSInteger nextPosition=start+moves[i];

            if ([self validDestination:nextPosition withMove:moves[i] fromSquare:start]) {
                if (![visitList containsIndex:nextPosition]) {
                    if ([self DFSFromStart:nextPosition toGoal:goal withLimit:limit-1 andVisitList:visitList]) {
                        return YES;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return NO;

}
-(BOOL) validDestination:(NSInteger)destination withMove:(int)move fromSquare:(NSInteger)start {

    if (destination <0 || destination >= BOARDWIDTH*BOARDHEIGHT) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (abs(move)==1) {
        int sourceRow= (int)start / BOARDWIDTH;
        int destinationRow=(int)destination / BOARDWIDTH;
        if (sourceRow != destinationRow) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**EDIT** I misread your question initially, so my code permitted diagonal moves.  I have fixed this

**EDIT 2** I have increased the DFS limit to 50 and added a new method to correctly check for valid moves - you can't move 'left' or 'right' to a different row.  - See the new method at the end and the call to that method in `DFSFromStart`

**EDIT 3** DFSFromStart didn't consider the validity of a move before comparing if the goal had been reached.

Comment: Hey, Creating a class was a great idea. Only thing is that when I tried out your code 1) when i click anywhere 3 new ones appear 2) I can't move a piece from 1 spot to another 3) How does it check for an open path if it doesn't move the pieces? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: Hi again. I fixed up the code a little to match my game but for some reason there are points where it says a move is invalid when its in reality Valid(this usually happens when its from one side of the board to the other) and Vis-Versa(idk when this happens, just randomly). Is there a max distance that it tries? Or any reason why it would get confused? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can increase the limit in the for loop in ’validmoveFromSquare`. It can take a bit of experimentation to find the right value but it is pretty fast, so you can safely double or even triple the limit for a start

Comment: Hey thank you for the help, Im still having some issues with it saying moves are valid when they aren't. It seems to be accepting diagonals some of the time (not often but once in a while) I switched the limit to 20 for (int limit=1;limit<20;limit++ ) . Any reason why it would think some moves are valid when they aren't? Thanks again -- Also just a possibility . Is it possible if a circle has the same color as it that it will think that circle is open? Probably not but the code seems good to me so I'm confused where its getting confused

Comment: The limit sets effectively how many "moves" are required to get from the start to the goal, so a limit of 20 means that the goal couldn't be reached after traversing 20 other circles.  In my testing, the limit of 10 seemed to work, let me look some more.

Comment: A limit of 50 seems to work OK, but I found a bigger bug - It considers a move from 54 to 53 to be valid "left" move - ie. across rows - let me think about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69347/discussion-between-user3080828-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to see if the current position is one tile away from the selected position.

There are a few steps to validate this. First, find the `difference` of the two positions. If the absolute difference of the two spots equals the length of each row (in this case, 9), then that means the selected position is either above or below your current position, making the move valid.

If that step fails, then you need to check if the two spots are next to each other, and if they are, make sure that they are in the same row. To do this, you see if the `difference` equals 1, and if it does, you divide each position by the length of the row and see if they are equal. What you're left with is something that would be similar to this:

```
int difference = Absolute(CURRENT - SELECTED)

int CURRENT_ROW_NUMBER = CURRENT / ROW_LENGTH
int SELECTED_ROW_NUMBER = SELECTED / ROW_LENGTH

if(difference == ROW_LENGTH)
{
    ValidMove();
}
else if(difference == 1 && CURRENT_ROW_NUMBER == SELECTED_ROW_NUMBER))
{
    ValidMove();
}
else
{
    InvalidMove();
}
```

I'm not too familiar with the language, but that's the logic behind what you're attempting.

Good luck with your game!

Comment: Hey just to confirm. This would work if the selected circle and the " move to position" we're more than 1 tile apart correct? Also does this allow diagonals? Sorry for all the questions. Thank you for the answer so far though

Comment: It does not allow diagonals, and it will only validate if the next position is either left, right, above, or below the current position. If the next position is on a different row, it will not validate.

Comment: Any idea how I could make it validate to any position on the grid?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking by that. The above process is for validating a current and next position given the rules that you've specified. In order to create more validation steps, there need to be different rules. What other positions are you deeming acceptable/valid?

Comment: Well if I wanted to move from #48 -> #1 (See picture above) would this code allow for that or not? Subsequently if I wanted to move from #79 - > #32 (see picture above again) would this code say that its an invalid move?

Comment: Well no, since they are not next to each other, it would not. You can plug in each number and check against the validation. Running through a few numbers for example:
#49 -> #50 is valid
#36 -> #45 is valid
#26 -> #27 is invalid
#48 -> #1 is invalid
etc...

Comment: That would work for only one path though correct? How could i get it to test every possible path and than return a true or false response ? Thank you for the help so far

Comment: Simply turn the above logic into a method (where ValidMove() is return true and InvalidMove() is return false). Make your parameters the current and next selections. When you have a "current" selection, loop through the entire list of tiles, where each one will be the "next" selection you're checking against.

Comment: Perfect! Thank You! If you add the code for the last part (the checking method) into your answer I'll up vote and check it off as the answer. Some of the code isn't written exactly in Objective C like Absolute would be ABS but i'll check it off anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Hey sorry to bother but Im having trouble implementing that last part. Could you post the code for it? I know its just looping through a method but I can't seem to figure it out. Sorry